# One view using multiple time in xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib

I would like make a pretty simple in my mind but really complicated when I tried to create. In a iPhone apps using XIB environnement, I want to create one view is

[image]

and using multiple time in my hold view controller is

[image]

and

[image]

how to use a this view in my view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id copyOfView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:viewOffer]];

UIView *viewOfferDisc = (UIView *)copyOfView;

viewOfferDisc.frame = CGRectMake(XAXIS, YAXIS, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```